# How to build a restful api while being private and members only?

Tags: php, web-services, authentication, rest, authorization

Back from the Symfony Live 2012 in Paris, where I luckily participate to "[Designing HTTP Interfaces and RESTful Web Services](http://paris2012.live.symfony.com/speakers#session-680)" conference, I'v much questions on how to build a RESTful API while keeping it private and member only.

Currently I used to generate an API key to make my API private (I mean available to third-party application on my own but end-users).

To make sure signed up users can use the API (through mobile app) I use Cookie, well, I used SESSION.

But afaik, it is not the correct way to do, according to the talk (and other resources I read over the web).

My needs are the following:

- Provides a private API which only my mobile app can use
- Allows member (of different roles) to do different actions (ie: a Member can post a comment, while an Administrator can edit them all)

As REST constraints are Stateless (amongst others) I can't use Cookie/Session as they need to be initiated by the client and will result in some non-idempotent result.

I read here and there that a way to keep my API RESTful is to provide on each request the credential.

Currently, to authenticate my API key (to keep it private) I use a custom HTTP Authorization scheme, something like `Authorization: MyApp SoMeToKeNV3RYPR!V4T3` and then authenticate my member (login) with a POST method (as I would do in any browser web application).

How would you implement such cases? Is it acceptable to use such private scheme and keep using sessions?

After some reading I may think that working with some Signature over each requests can help to solve such problems.

The signature may be generated using the user credential provided in the third-party client while encrypting it with a public/private key (to keep the API private).

On each request, the signature will be checked against a CRC (or something like that) while the credential will be against a database (it doesn't seem worth than checking for a session, does it?)

Any help/advices would be appreciated.

PS: What about OAuth? I don't know much about it, but may it be a solution to such problem?

Answer (score 1):

You're definitely going to want to use [OAuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth). This will allow you to securely authenticate that your users are who they say they are. No messing with CRCs or anything is needed on your end, once a user is authenticated they have an access token they can use to sign future requests.

You would just need to handle the authentication scheme and handshake and then securely store the access tokens once they have been given out. However, if it were me I would not trust myself to handle all of the secure cases when designing such a system. There are a couple of third party PaaS companies that will do this type of thing for you. I know of the following companies which have some API management tools that will probably help you, and afaik they handle OAuth implementations as well:

- [Apigee](http://apigee.com/)
- [Layer 7](http://www.layer7tech.com/)
- [Ping Identity](https://www.pingidentity.com/)

If you are so concerned about security though that you don't trust a third party to handle it for you you are going to want to follow the [OAuth protocol](http://oauth.net/).

Comment: Thanks, for sure using a well (?) designed protocol like OAuth is surely the way to go, but from REST/HTTP point of view, it doesn't seem to be RESTFul, authentication has to be done in a specific sequence order and break the REST definition of being Stateless. I'm not against breaking the rules, real world use cases don't always fit theory, but I'm wondering what are the alternative to keep, strictly speaking, the theory real.

Comment: The future requests are Stateless, the idea is once a user is authenticated that process is done (unless you want the token to expire). All subsequent requests after the OAuth handshake is done are "signed" with the access token they were provided. You can think of that "signing" as just another http header that comes through that you check against. Most RESTful APIs that you will find will use OAuth as their authentication mechanism in my experience